# Why does `sp.pack('some string')` prepend `0x05010000002e` before the actual bytes?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, encoding, bytes

If I pass in the string `QmbPAr5RcCZZDRsNKnf2p1t6GK3Qu7oDH39HCK3aewUq3w` to the `sp.pack` method in an entrypoint and perform and `sp.trace` in smartpy I expect to get the following bytes:

`0x516d62504172355263435a5a4452734e4b6e663270317436474b335175376f4448333948434b3361657755713377`

However, I receive the following bytes:

`0x05010000002e516d62504172355263435a5a4452734e4b6e663270317436474b335175376f4448333948434b3361657755713377`

You can see that the bytes `0x05010000002e` are being prepended to the value during the pack

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x05` means "this is a packed Michelson value". `0x01` means "this is a string". The remaining 4 bytes represent the length of the string.

A complete description of the binary format of Michelson values can be generated by the following command: `tezos-codec describe alpha.script.expr binary schema`.

Comment: interesting.. thank you. do you know if it is possible to turn a string sent into an entrypoint into its raw bytes representation within the entrypoint? i thought `sp.pack` would do this, and while `sp.utils.bytes_of_string` gives the right answer it is only available at compile time

Comment: i expanded this comment into a full question: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/how-do-you-convert-a-string-sent-to-an-entrypoint-into-its-byte-representation