# How do you convert a string sent to an entrypoint into its byte representation?

Tags: smartpy, encoding, string, bytes

I want to turn a string into the `0x` byte format inside an entrypoint.

If I try to use `sp.pack()` the actual value I want gets prepended with pack instructions as [detailed here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3999/why-does-sp-packsome-string-prepend-0x05010000002e-before-the-actual-byt)

I'm looking for a runtime equivalent of `sp.utils.bytes_of_string()` (which can only be used at compile time) that does not prepend anything to the string.

Is it possible to do this inside an entrypoint with smartpy?

Comment: Are you sure you have to use strings in the first place? All operations on strings are also available on bytes.

Comment: yes, the entrypoint accepts a normal ipfs cid in string representation, and prepends `ipfs://` to the received string in-contract before persisting it as the pointer to the tokens metadata, so it need to turn into its hex representation to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled on this for a while but finally reached a solution.

It's a bit hacky, but you just have to remove the 6 bytes that `sp.pack` prepends onto the bytes you actually want with `sp.slice` before using them.

```
padding = 6
string_length = sp.len(params.meta) + padding + 1

packed_string = sp.slice(
    sp.pack(params.meta),
    padding,
    string_length
).open_some()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the utilities provided in this repository: [tezos-sc-utils](https://github.com/RomarQ/tezos-sc-utils/blob/main/smartpy/README.md#documentation)

It provides utilities to encode and decode strings.

Here is an example of it working in SmartPy IDE:
https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmbNMohfAQQqnG98aL1Rj3y5Y4KBJ7Vo9pWuMBfsCHy9mX&k=5ec3179b99a5aab6609e